# Multiple LIKE statements in query

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, mariadb

I am currently working on search engine for baking recipes, the site returns recipes based on the ingredients that the user has. I only want to return the recipes where BOTH ingredients are present in, in some kind of form. I tried the following SQL statement, but i cant seem to get it to work propperly with the AND in between, it works fine with OR or without the AND.

```
SELECT * FROM ingredients WHERE name LIKE '%flower%' AND name LIKE '%egg%'
```

It doenst throw any errors it just says that there arent any results, which is odd as the first recipe has already bot ingredients in it.

I hope someone can help me out! Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you sure both ingredients appear in the **name**?

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: And see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: It seems you don't understand how the logical operators work. The fact that in everyday speech may sound like “choose A and B” in the SQL will be expressed as “SELECT * WHERE x = 'A' OR x = 'B' ”.
In SQL, logical operators only work inside a single entry. This is not a union of entries.

Comment: Give a couple of examples of rows that should match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM ingredients i
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING SUM(name LIKE '%flower%') > 0 AND
       SUM(name LIKE '%egg%') > 0;
```

Note that "flower"s are unlikely to be in a recipe (although there are some!).  "flour" is much more common.

Comment: This one worked just as fine as the other i commented on. Solves my problem! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the table first and then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT recipe_id
FROM ingredients 
WHERE name LIKE '%flower%' OR name LIKE '%egg%'
GROUP BY recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
  WHEN name LIKE '%flower%' THEN 1
  WHEN name LIKE '%egg%' THEN 2
END) = 2
```

Comment: This one worked just great and solves my problem! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve it via sub-query and HAVING COUNT trick.
Let's suppose we have salad and soup recipes. (Forgive me my weird compositions)

```
id, recipe_name
--- -----------
1, 'Summer salad'
2, 'Italian soup'
```

and theirs respective ingredients

```
id, recipe_id, ing_name, ing_amount
--- ---------- --------- ----------
1, 1, 'egg', 200
2, 1, 'flower', 300
3, 1, 'parsley', 10
4, 1, 'salt', 5

5, 2, 'egg', 200
6, 2, 'salt', 15
```

IF our aim is to show recipes where ALL enumerated records exist, use such kind of query:

```sql
SELECT recipes.*
FROM recipes
JOIN (
  SELECT recipe_id
  FROM ingredients
  WHERE 
    ing_name LIKE '%flower%' OR
    ing_name LIKE '%egg%'
  GROUP BY recipe_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) AS g ON g.recipe_id = recipes.id
```

i.e. combine conditions by OR operator and then count how many of them are true.
`c1 OR c2 OR c3 GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/patGWSvVjZ7Brz6eF5zqSn/0